# WP7 List Box acting strangely... using .focus() method

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, listbox

I have 8 TextBox for the input in my list box... for the ease of user i have used the following code

```
    private void txtFirstName_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter || e.PlatformKeyCode == 0x0A)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            txtLastName.Focus();
        }
    }
```

so whenever user finished input in first text box & press enter automatically next textbox get focus & user can continue entering data... no need to select next textbox again

but the problem is out of 8 textboxes there are onscreen only 5 textboxes so for the 6 input listbox needs to scroll down if user click enter in 5th textbox & 6th textbox get focus it dosent shown on the screen but after 5th textbox there is a black space emerged from down & it continues till the last textbox.... but input is correctly entered everywhere just while typing & auto focusing last three boxes dosent show up on the screen instead of that black screen appears....

but this does not happen when i delete the auto focus & user have to personally click on text box & start entering input so whats the actual problem here what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use listBox.ScrollIntoView(itemInWhichTheTextBoxIsIn); to scroll the the item in the ListBox into view before setting the Focus on the TextBox.

Comment: yup this is the solution